# Add more columns to table using multicolumn

Tags: tables, templates

I am using a template for publishing a paper in conference. There I have a code for making a table but I am not able to add column to table using that code. I would be grateful for explaining me the code and how to add column and row using the code. The code is given below.

What is the use of `{\rule{0pt}{12pt}` and `[2pt]` in the code. The table is not affected even after I remove these from it.

The screen shot of the table I want to create is given below:

[image]

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Stir casting factors and their levels }
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{r@{\quad}rl}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\rule{0pt}{12pt}
                   Year}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{World population}\\[2pt]
\hline\rule{0pt}{12pt}
8000 B.C.  &     5,000,000& \\
  50 A.D.  &   200,000,000& \\
1650 A.D.  &   500,000,000& \\
1945 A.D.  & 2,300,000,000& \\
1980 A.D.  & 4,400,000,000&\\[2pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: please have alook at the answer below -- the `rule` adds an invisible vertical line of 12pt to add some extra space `inside` the row  -- the 2pt gives extra spacing `between` the two rows

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: What is the aim of adding a column here, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question isn't entirely clear, and several answers have provided further details, I'd recommend using [this latex table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/) to understand how the codes function interactively.

It's a good resource.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not entirely clear.

- In table's code are already three columns, however you use only first two. What should be in the third column?
- Do you like to add fourth column?
- Unfortunately you provide only table's code fragment, so we can only guess about your document preamble.
- Number of columns is determined by number of column specification in tabular (or other type of table). In your case are defined tree with `r`, `r` and `l` column specifiers (for aligning column contents to right, right and left)
- The use of `\rule{0pt}{12pt}` is used to add vertical space above cells contents at the first two rows.
- The `\\[2pt]` at last row insert 2pt gap before last `\hline`.
- The environment `center`, i.e. `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` introduce additional vertical space above and below table. Better is use just `\centering` command before `tabular`.

I guess, that your table could be as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}   % for horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{siunitx}    % for writing numbers, units and for `S` columns 

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Stir casting factors and their levels}
\label{tab: ...}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{r S[table-format=10.0] 
                  S[table-format=3.2]
                  S[table-format=3.2]}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Year}        
            & {World population} 
                            & {???}   & {???}   \\
    \midrule
8000 B.C.  &     5 000 000  & 123.45  &  67.89  \\
  50 A.D.  &   200 000 000  & 123.45  & 167.89  \\
1650 A.D.  &   500 000 000  & 123.45  &  67.89  \\
1945 A.D.  & 2 300 000 000  & 123.45  & 2 67.89 \\
1980 A.D.  & 4 400 000 000  & 123.45  &  67.89  \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

In comparison to your table code example the table in the above MWE (Minimal Working Example) are used

- `S` columns type for numbers, which enable to align numbers at decimal points (see third and fourth column) or right side, if numbers are integers (as are in the second column).
- rules `\toprule`, `midrule` and `bottomrule` qhich add some additional vertical space around them and by this make table looks more "profesional`:

[image]

Comment: My question may not be clear but you have understood it correctly. Actually there are three columns and I want to add one more as you have done. Thanks a lot It is perfectly what I wanted@Zarko

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\begin{table} \caption{Stir casting factors and their levels } \begin{center} 
 \begin{tabular}{r@{\quad}rl} \hline 
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{\rule{0pt}{12pt} Year}&
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{World population}\\[2pt] \hline\rule{0pt}{12pt} 
            8000 B.C. & 
            5,000,000 \\
            50 A.D. & 
            200,000,000 \\
            1650 A.D. & 
            500,000,000 \\
            1945 A.D. & 
            2,300,000,000 \\
            1980 A.D. & 
            4,400,000,000\\[2pt] \hline 
        \end{tabular} \end{center} \end{table}
```

edit

[image]

```
\begin{table} \caption{Stir casting factors and their levels } \begin{center} 
  \begin{tabular}{r@{\quad}rl l} \hline 
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{\rule{0pt}{12pt} Year}&
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{World population}     &
            ADD \\[2pt] \hline\rule{0pt}{12pt}
            8000 B.C. & 
            5,000,000 && added now\\
            50 A.D. & 
            200,000,000 \\
            1650 A.D. & 
            500,000,000 \\
            1945 A.D. & 
            2,300,000,000 \\
            1980 A.D. & 
            4,400,000,000\\[2pt] \hline 
        \end{tabular} \end{center} \end{table}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but this code is given in template and I want to add a column as shown in my image

Comment: see edit  - add `l` for left aligned coln in {rrll} for number of colns  -- add the content below in the table -- each`&` is column separator

Comment: Thanks @js bibra